# How do I mount ext2 or ext3 filesystems on OSX?

Tags: mac-osx, ext3, ext2

I would like to mount an ext2/3 filesystem on a mac running 10.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://digg.com/apple/Mounting_Linux_ext2_ext3_using_MacFUSE_under_Mac_OS_X

is recent, and links to http://ekettoz.blogspot.com/2009/06/mounting-linux-ext2ext3-partitions.html

which references http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/

This project has releases from December 2008 to June 2009. I know I have some MacFUSE driver for Ext2 at home, but I am at work right now. I can check which one I have back there. It works well, whatever it is.

Comment: I think whatever your best answer will be, it will use MacFUSE somewhere. I use MacFUSE for accessing my NTFS drives, read and write, without problem (so far - knockonwood).

Comment: That's the right way to do this. I'm using the ext2fsx driver now and it works, but I'll switch to this soon. Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsx/ appears to do the trick.

I should have asked Google before asking ServerFault. In any case, I'll leave the answer here for others.

Comment: Note that this code hasn't been updated since 2006.  I don't know about you, but I wouldn't trust an open source project that hasn't been maintained in 3 years.

Comment: I had that same thought, Maybe there will be a better solution offered by the someone else. In the meantime, I'll use that one.

Comment: Although, even if it's from 2006, Ext2/3 hasn't changed a whole lot. According to Wikipedia, it was introduced in 1993, so a 2006 driver has 13 years of history (theoretically) behind it. Likewise, 2001 for Ext3.